# Calling a method inside another method within the same class function

Tags: python-3.x, class, methods, nested, scipy-optimize-minimize

I'm trying to calibrate a model that has 12 unknown parameters inside it and as input only 5. I'm building a class for it as for example:

```
class model:

def __init__(self,input_1,input_2,input_3,...):
    self.input_1=input_1
    self.input_2=input_2
    self.input_3=input_3
    .
    . 
    . #Only inputs here, no pmts
Then I've defined the functions as:

def integral(self, input_1, pmt1, pm2, pm3.... )

integral,err= quad(f(input,pmt1,pmt2,pmt3)) #I'm simplifying here, the function is longer

    return integral


def model_price(self,input_1,input_2,input_3):

     price = pm3 + self.integral(self)/input_3

   return price

def loss_function(self):

   err = (self.input_1 - self.model_price)
   pen = 0 

   return err + pen


def minimization(self,x0,bnds):

 params = {"pm1": {"x0": 0.0746, "lbub": [1e-4,4.9]},  #1
              "pmt2": {"x0": 0.3369, "lbub": [1e-4,4]}, #2
              "pm3": {"x0": 0.3369, "lbub": [1e-4,4]}, #3
                  ....
           }

    x0 = [param["x0"] for key, param in params.items()]
    bnds = [param["lbub"] for key, param in params.items()]
    results =minimize(self.loss_function(), x0, tol = 1e-3, method='SLSQP', options={'maxiter': 1e3 }, bounds=bnds)
            
    return results
```

I tried passing the x0 and bounds outside the function when I tried to use but is not working. I always get:

```
TypeError: integral() missing 12 required positional arguments: 'pmt1, pmt2, pmt3,
```

Answer (score 0):

Error message is pretty clear, you are trying to call method `integral` with single argument and you need to pass 12 arguments.

So instead of `self.integral(self)`  you need `self.integral(arg1, … , arg12)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but actually I'm trying to calibrate those parameters therefore I know only the range where they could be and an initial guess. Is there any solution to that?

Comment: Did you try to use then ‘*args’ https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/args_and_kwargs.html

That will help you passing dynamic list of arguments

Comment: Still not working even with **args